# Laravel Tinker Create new entry base table not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add a new user to my table 'Users' created by the migrate command. However, i get this error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'scontrol_Database.users' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`, `isactive`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

I am confused as I have run composer dump-autoload and refreshed everything but nothing works so far. This is my schema:

```
Schema::create('Users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('isactive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Please help.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? I have tried so many methods but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and **case sensitive** in most varieties of Unix or Linux.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('isactive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'scontrol_Database.users' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`, `isactive`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test@test.com, $2y$10$QbE5P.ckV0yudlA12pKVo.CxAWwwFhenjQQcPhbOLl..bG/Be7qMi, 1, 2017-04-05 13:05:40, 2017-04-05 13:05:40))'

Comment: so the same. do you have same acces to database? can you check if the table really does not exist?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yup! I can access the database and a migrations table and a Users table have been created

Comment: Table name is with Uppercase "U"? If so, try changing it to lowercase.

Comment: oh! It worked! Thank you so much! I've been spending so long trying to get this to work. Must be because of the lowercase and migrate:refresh